# Spiltting Strings into Array Lists

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

A friend is working on some homework. He has to take account numbers from an input file, check for account duplicates, calculate the cost using piecewise formula, then add them by account to display as an itemized bill. It's essentially the same homework found [here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/330308-getting-total-bill-per-account-for-a-phone-bill/).

It's hard since it's intro to java and I'm not very good. We're getting two errors: one is there's an Array out of bounds exception and two is the file checking. Since we use a for loop to calculate the account cost per call we can't keep track of previous account numbers to check. I suggested an ArrayList to keep hold of previous accounts and to check for duplicates but we can't figure out how to split into a separate ArrayList.

We have this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException{

    ArrayList<String> acctHolder = new ArrayList<String>();
    String tmp = "";

    File fInput = new File("input_data.txt");

    Scanner scInput = null;
    scInput = new Scanner(fInput);         
    while (scInput.hasNextLine()){
        tmp = scInput.nextLine();
        acctHolder.add(tmp);
    }

    scInput.close();

    DecimalFormat twoDForm = new DecimalFormat("#.##");

    String acctNum = null;
    String timeMin = null;
    String totalTime = null;
    double feeCost = 0;
    double totalCost = 0;
    double finalTotal = 0;
    double sum = 0;


    final double DAYRATE = 0.12;
    final double NIGHTRATE = 0.05;
    final double BASEFEE = 20.0;

    ArrayList<Double> aTCost = new ArrayList<Double>();

    System.out.println("Invoice");
    System.out.println("*****************************");
    System.out.println("Account    \t     Amount Due");


    for(int i = 1; i < acctHolder.size(); i++)
    {

        String[] result = ((String) acctHolder.get(i)).split(" ");

        acctNum = result[0];
        timeMin = result[1];
        totalTime = result[2];

        double tTime = Double.parseDouble(totalTime);

        String morningTime = "08:00";
        String nightTime = "22:00";
        DateFormat timeMins = new SimpleDateFormat("kk:mm");
        Date callTime = timeMins.parse(timeMin);
        Date dawnTime = timeMins.parse(morningTime);
        Date niteTime = timeMins.parse(nightTime);

        if(callTime.compareTo(dawnTime) > 0 && callTime.compareTo(niteTime) < 0 )
        {
            feeCost = tTime * DAYRATE;   
            totalCost = feeCost + BASEFEE; 
        }
        else
        {
            feeCost = tTime * NIGHTRATE;
            //totalCost = feeCost + BASEFEE;   
        }


        aTCost.add(totalCost);

        //double sum = 0;
        for(Double d : aTCost)
            sum += d;




        System.out.println(acctNum + "               $"+ feeCost);

    }            
    //for(int i = 0; i < acctHolder)
    System.out.println("*****************************");
    System.out.println("Total                " + sum);

}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask] first.  Generally it is not acceptable to post a large amount of code and say "please find the bug".  You must first use an IDE debugger (Eclipse, NetBeans, Idea, etc) and trace through the program step by step if necessary until you find where things don't do what you expect.  If you still have a question after that, then narrow down the code to a minimal example that demonstrates the question.  Oh, and only ONE question per post.

Comment: There's a lot of code there... but just in response to the question summary, I'm going to guess you might find this useful: http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html

Comment: Your method is way too big; it can easily be broken down into small, individually-testable methods. For example, the code to read a file into an `ArrayList` should be its own method.

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code with the sample data from the link, and got the following result:

```
Invoice
*****************************
Account          Amount Due
10011               $1.224
10011               $1.476
10033               $1.7000000000000002
*****************************
Total                128.1
```

So, I can't reproduce the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` (my best guess is that in the file you were reading you had less than 3 fields in one of the lines, so `result[2]` was out of bounds).

The second problem I can see, is that you are using `Double`. That is why one of the results is "1.7000000000000002" instead of "1.7". You should have a look at `BigDecimal`, and search for "double problems" or "float problems" on a search engine.

The third problem is that you are adding all the previous costs to `sum` for each line on the file. This is why your total sum is so high. You have to put the summing loop outside the loop one the lines.

And for grouping the results by accounts, what you need is not and `ArrayList`, but a `HashMap`, using the account number as key.

Answer (score 0):

```
                   import java.util.ArrayList;
                   import java.util.Arrays;                    
                   String stringToSplit = "1,2,3,4,5";
                   ArrayList<String> arrayFromString =new ArrayList<String>( 
                   Arrays.asList(stringToSplit.split(",")));
```

You can Splite and Store in array List